# jQuery regex replace html variables

Tags: jquery, regex

What would be the regex to remove a variable string like the following in the html?

```
<% include Banner %>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$('body').html().replace('<%(.*?)%>','');
```

Comment: Are you sure that actually exists as of the time you're trying to operate on it? Because frankly, I doubt it.

Comment: Looks a lot like EJS or some other serverside templating system ?

Comment: Silverstripe template system. I'm using jQuery .load to display pre-generated .ss template includes based on a customised online order to speed up dev and html/css cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to set your html, **turn your regex into a regex** and change your `<` to `&lt;`

```
var $body = $('body');
$body.html($body.html().replace(/&lt;%(.*?)%&gt;/,''));
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7nWyA/**

If jQuery finds `<` and `>` when it's not actually a html tag it will replace it with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: +1 `and turn your regex into a regex` The sentence of the day